# Keep HTML window open till user closes it

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I get a mobile number from the user. I will check and capture existing records in a HTML. I want to display this to the user and then I want to ask the user to enter choice whether to add a new record or not.

The below code is working. Only problem is the HTML window is closing on its own. The user is not able to view it.

I want the HTML must be closed manually before the next step.

Any help will be appreciated.

I am open to any other method.

```
function book_new_call() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var today=new Date();
  var newcust=true;
  var cusmob =  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt("Enter Customer Mobile No").getResponseText();
  var cussht = ss.getSheetByName("Cust_Mast");
  var cuslr=cussht.getLastRow()
  var titles = cussht.getRange("A1:G1").getValues();
  var vA = cussht.getRange("A:G").getValues();
  var html="Cust Master<style>th,td{border:1px solid black;}</style><table>";
  for(var i=1;i< cuslr ;i++) {
    if (vA[i][0]==cusmob  || vA[i][4]==cusmob  ) {
      newcust=false;
      if (vA[i][4]==cusmob){vA[i][0]=cusmob; cusmob = vA[i][0] };
      for(var j=0;j<=6;j++) {
        if ( vA[i][j] =="") {} else {
          if (j==5){
            vA[i][j]=Utilities.formatDate(vA[i][j],"GMT+05:30", "dd-MM-yy");
          }//if date
          html+='<tr>';
          html+=Utilities.formatString('<th>%s</th>',titles[0][j]);
          html+=Utilities.formatString('<td>%s</td>',vA[i][j]);
          html+='</tr>'};//if
      }//for j
    }//if item match
  }//for i
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  //SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, cusmob );
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(userInterface, cusmob );
  if (newcust) {
    var choice =  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt("1 to add customer and Call, 2 to add customer only").getResponseText();
    if (choice=="1") {
      cussht.appendRow([cusmob]); 
      var nxcall=1+calsht.getRange("A"+callr).getValue();
      calsht.appendRow([ nxcall,today,"",cusmob]);
    } 
    if (choice=="2") {
      cussht.appendRow([cusmob]); 
    }
  } else {
    var choice =  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt("1 to add Call").getResponseText();
    //var response = Browser.msgBox('Do you want to add new customer and register new call', 'Press Yes or Cancel', Browser.Buttons.YES_NO);
    if (choice=="1") {
      var nxcall=1+calsht.getRange("A"+callr).getValue();
      calsht.appendRow([ nxcall,today,"",cusmob]);
      calsht.activate();
    } else {
      if (pcalls>0) {calsht.getRange("A"+pcall).activate()} else {
          if (ccalls>0) { calsht.getRange("A"+ccall).activate() } }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to keep the dialog of `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(userInterface, cusmob )`, until the user close the dialog.

### Modification points:

- When `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(userInterface, cusmob )` is run, the process of this dialog is released from the process of the running function. By this, the next script of the function is run. So `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt()` overwrites the existing dialog. By this, `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(userInterface, cusmob )` is removed soon. I think that this is the reason of your issue.

In order to achieve your goal, I would like to propose the following 2 patterns.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the sidebar is used instead of the dialog. In this case, please modify your script as follows.

#### From:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(userInterface, cusmob );
```

#### To:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(userInterface.setTitle(cusmob));
```

### Pattern 2:

When you are required to use the dialog, in this pattern, the dialog of `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(userInterface, cusmob );` is used. Please modify your script as follows.

In this pattern, after `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(userInterface.evaluate(), cusmob)` was run, `next()` function is run with `google.script.run` by clicking "OK" button. But in this case, it is required to send the parameters for using the function `next()`. From your script, I sent the variables of `[newcust, cussht.getSheetName(), calsht.getSheetName(), cusmob, callr, pcalls, pcall, today.toISOString()]`. And, the sheet name and date string are converted to the sheet object and the date object in `next()`, respectively.

#### From:

```
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  //SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, cusmob );
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(userInterface, cusmob );
  if (newcust) {
    var choice =  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt("1 to add customer and Call, 2 to add customer only").getResponseText();
    if (choice=="1") {
      cussht.appendRow([cusmob]); 
      var nxcall=1+calsht.getRange("A"+callr).getValue();
      calsht.appendRow([ nxcall,today,"",cusmob]);
    } 
    if (choice=="2") {
      cussht.appendRow([cusmob]); 
    }
  } else {
    var choice =  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt("1 to add Call").getResponseText();
    //var response = Browser.msgBox('Do you want to add new customer and register new call', 'Press Yes or Cancel', Browser.Buttons.YES_NO);
    if (choice=="1") {
      var nxcall=1+calsht.getRange("A"+callr).getValue();
      calsht.appendRow([ nxcall,today,"",cusmob]);
      calsht.activate();
    } else {
      if (pcalls>0) {calsht.getRange("A"+pcall).activate()} else {
          if (ccalls>0) { calsht.getRange("A"+ccall).activate() } }
    }
  }
}
```

#### To:

```
  html += '<input type="button" value="ok" onclick="next()"><script>function next() {google.script.run.next(JSON.parse(<?= JSON.stringify(values) ?>))}</script>';
  var userInterface = HtmlService.createTemplate(html);
  userInterface.values = [newcust, cussht.getSheetName(), calsht.getSheetName(), cusmob, callr, pcalls, pcall, today.toISOString()];
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(userInterface.evaluate(), cusmob);
}

function next([newcust, cussht, calsht, cusmob, callr, pcalls, pcall, today]) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  cussht = ss.getSheetByName(cussht);
  calsht = ss.getSheetByName(calsht);
  today = new Date(today);

  if (newcust) {
    var choice =  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt("1 to add customer and Call, 2 to add customer only").getResponseText();
    if (choice=="1") {
      cussht.appendRow([cusmob]); 
      var nxcall=1+calsht.getRange("A"+callr).getValue();
      calsht.appendRow([ nxcall,today,"",cusmob]);
    } 
    if (choice=="2") {
      cussht.appendRow([cusmob]); 
    }
  } else {
    var choice =  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt("1 to add Call").getResponseText();
    //var response = Browser.msgBox('Do you want to add new customer and register new call', 'Press Yes or Cancel', Browser.Buttons.YES_NO);
    if (choice=="1") {
      var nxcall=1+calsht.getRange("A"+callr).getValue();
      calsht.appendRow([ nxcall,today,"",cusmob]);
      calsht.activate();
    } else {
      if (pcalls>0) {calsht.getRange("A"+pcall).activate()} else {
          if (ccalls>0) { calsht.getRange("A"+ccall).activate() } }
    }
  }
}
```

### Note:

- In your script, there are several variables which are not declared in the function. So please be careful this. And, if you want to use more variables, please modify the script.
- Above scripts are the simple modifications. So please modify them for your actual situation.

### References:

- [Dialogs and Sidebars in Google Workspace Documents](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs)
- [HTML Service: Templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)

Comment: as always, your help is of top quality. Both the patterns are working. The Sidebar is becoming dark, so I am not going to use it. The pattern 2 is working perfectly. Thanks a ton

Comment: @arul selvan Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.